# How to create a bubble legend in Carto?

Tags: carto, legend, html

I have generated a 'bubble' map in Carto:

[image]

Custom CSS:

```
#layer {
    [capacity >= 70000]  
    {marker-width: 90;
    }
    [capacity >= 60000][capacity < 70000]  
    {marker-width: 80;}
    [capacity >= 50000][capacity < 60000]
      {marker-width: 70;}
    [capacity >= 40000][capacity < 50000]
       {marker-width: 60;}
    [capacity >= 30000][capacity < 40000]
      {marker-width: 50;}
    [capacity >= 20000][capacity < 30000]
       {marker-width: 40;}
    [capacity <= 20000]
       {marker-width: 30;}
 marker-fill: teal;
    marker-fill-opacity: 0.5;
    marker-line-color: #FFF;
    marker-line-width: 1;
    marker-line-opacity: 0.8;
    marker-placement: point;
    marker-type: ellipse;
    marker-allow-overlap: true;
  }
```

However there is no option to create a bubble style legend. I have looked at several examples to use custom html to implement this, however none seem to generate what i am after.

The question - [CartoDB choropleth + bubble visualization with two independent value ranges in legend](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/148500/cartodb-choropleth-bubble-visualization-with-two-independent-value-ranges-in-l) seems to show what I am after but the code supplied does not seem to behave the same my end

```
    <div class='cartodb-legend bubble'> 
 <ul>
  <li>
  1.46
  </li>
  <li class="graph" style="background: linear-gradient(to right,rgb(253, 141, 60), rgb(252, 78, 42), rgb(177, 0, 38));">
    <div class="bubbles"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
  18.5
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I don't expect this to suddenly work with my data but I don't understand why I return:

[image]

Instead of:

[image]

Has the functionality of 'cartodb-legend bubble' changed at all?

Answer (score 3):

The question and code work for Editor, the former CARTO web UI. According to the screenshot, the map was created using BUILDER, the new CARTO web UI. Bubble and choropleth legends are generated dynamically (and automatically) after [styling `BY VALUE`](https://carto.com/learn/guides/styling/style-by-value). So in your case, if the legend is not showing I recommend following these steps to recover it:

1. Click on the layer.
2. Go to the `LEGEND` tab.
3. Click on `SIZE`.
4. Select `BUBBLE`.

**UPDATE:**

In order to replicate the CartoCSS code you have shared and at the same time getting a bubble legend follow these steps:

1. Go to the `STYLE` tab.
2. Switch to the UI and click on `CLEAR`.
3. Click on the marker width (it shows `7` by default) and select `BY VALUE`, then choose `capacity` field from the drop-down menu.
4. Switch the slider button to show the CartoCSS panel again.
5. Apply the following CartoCSS code:

> ```
> #layer {
>     marker-width: ramp([capacity], (30,40,50,60,70,80), (20000,30000,40000,50000,60000,70000), >);   
>     marker-fill: teal;
>     marker-fill-opacity: 0.5;
>     marker-line-color: #FFF;
>     marker-line-width: 1;
>     marker-line-opacity: 0.8;
>     marker-placement: point;
>     marker-type: ellipse;
>     marker-allow-overlap: true;
>   }
> ```

7. Apply.

You will end up with a visualization similar to this one but with a nice legend. I have used [this app](http://bl.ocks.org/ramiroaznar/raw/5a10c324dd0f4230f20db75b671a3eda/) to adjust the bubbles sizes. :-)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response @ramiroaznar, unfortunately there are no options to select when i click on the 'size' tab, it just says NONE. I used my own css styling to generate different marker-widths. Is there a simple piece of html I could use here?

Comment: Legends are generated by using the UI but behind the scenes is applying a TurboCARTO ramp. Could you share the custom CartoCSS? I believe I will be able todo make a workaround.

Comment: Custom CSS has been added to original question @ramiroaznar. Is 'Editor' still available for public use? perhaps this would be the easiest option.

Comment: I have updated my answer. CARTO is migrating all users to BUILDER, so Editor is not available for new and migrated users.

Comment: Getting closer. Changing the value to capacity from another value I had previously been looking at has given a legend. I can't seem to get it to apply the width values I have manually styled with. I think the ramp function will do this however I get the following error with your code? Syntax error. Line 2: Invalid code: marker-width: ramp([capacity], (30,40,50,60,70,80), (20000,30000,40000,50000,60000,70000), >);

Comment: Could you send the carto file to support@carto.com?